# Can't read the plist

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I'm having trouble with a method to read my plist:

```
@synthesize data //NSMutableArray

-(void)readPlist{
plistFilePath = [NSString stringWithString:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myPlist" ofType:@"plist"]];   
    data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistFilePath];
    //here I use data, it doesn't matter for what
    [data release
}
```

If I do `NSLog(@"%@", data)` after `data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile : plistFilePath];` Xcode says data's empty. I can't find any error in the code, what's wrong?

Comment: Are you sure plistFilePath is not nil?

Comment: Can you verify that the contents are valid?  Will it open in XCode?

Comment: These are the contents of the plist: http://cl.ly/2q2a310b1m2P0o0A2j3Y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your plist is not an array, it is a dictionary, so you should be using NSMutableDictionary instead.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use NSDictionary object to read a plist file.

**dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:**
Creates and returns a dictionary using the keys and values found in a file specified by a given path.

- (id)dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path
  **Parameters:

  path**
  A full or relative pathname. The file identified by path must contain a string representation of a property list whose root object is a dictionary.
  **Return Value** 
  A new dictionary that contains the dictionary at path, or nil if there is a file error or if the contents of the file are an invalid representation of a dictionary.